# mongoengine NotUniqueError on empty collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to save the first object to a collection (I did db.connection.drop_database() to ensure it is the first object), but I keep getting the `*** NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys` error.

Here's a quick example of what I get:

```
ipdb> Card.objects.all()  
[]  
ipdb> card  
`<Card: <Card url/pk: c569e1c9-7311-441e-ba03-0e86d4bc2932>>`  
ipdb> card.save()  
*** NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: contacts.dav_object.$username_1  dup key: { : null })  
ipdb> Card.drop_collection()  
ipdb> card.save()  
`<Card: <Card url/pk: c569e1c9-7311-441e-ba03-0e86d4bc2932>>`  
ipdb>
```

I'm using UnitTest, and the `setUp` method has `Card.ensure_indexes()`. I suspect it has something to do with it, but without this line Mongo will accept duplicated entries, even if the model definition says `unique=True`.

If I add `Card._collection.drop_indexes()` after the `Card.ensure_indexes()` this problem goes away, but then I get duplicated entries, just like I said above.

Here's Card Model:

```
class Card(DavObject):  
    addressbook = db.ReferenceField("Addressbook")  
    url = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True, unique_with=["addressbook", "url"])  
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)  
    text = db.StringField(required=True)
```

And here's DavObject:

```
class DavObject(db.Document):
    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': True,
    }

    last_update = db.ComplexDateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"<%s url/pk: %s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, getattr(self, "url", self.pk))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._get_changed_fields():
            self.last_update = datetime.utcnow()
        return db.Document.save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

I'm using mongoengine 0.8.3, flask 0.10.1 and python 2.7.3.

Comment: Can you show `Card` model defenition?

Comment: Updated the question, there's the Card model and the model it inherits from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like problem with inheritance: you set up `'allow_inheritance': True` for `DavObject` it means that all inherited models will store in one collection.

You have `username` index for some model inherited from `DavObject` and it have conflict when you trying insert two inherited from `DavObject` documents with same `username` (None).

If you not shure that you need use `'allow_inheritance': True` than set it to `False` or try put documents with different indexes to separate collections.

To check my assumption try `print list(DavObject.objects.all())`.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Thanks man, I was on this bug for more than 48 hours now.

Comment: Just adding one more information, this was solved by simply adding `'abstract': True` to the `DavObject` `meta` dictionary.